# Moving files only linux

Tags: linux, mv

I have a path /participant/data where all the files are in the data directory.
However, I want the directory-structure to be /participant/data/subdirectory, with subdirectory containing all the files. It needs to be like this for it to pass a pipeline.

My first thought was

mkdir /participant/data/subdirectory/

mv /participant/data/*.*  /participant/data/subdirectory/

However, the files don't have a file-extention, so using *.* won't work.
Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: You're overthinking this. `*.*` means "anything, followed by a dot, followed by anything". Just don't require the dot: `*`

Answer (score 2):

Just move everything:

```
mv /participant/data/* /participant/data/subdirectory/
```

This will complain about not being able to move `subdirectory` into itself, but will still move everything else into that subdirectory the way you wanted.

Bash's `shopt -s extglob` adds a few additional wildcard characters, such as `!(xy|z)` to match everything like `*` *except* `xy` or `z`:

```
shopt -s extglob
mv /participant/data/!(subdir) /participant/data/subdir/
```

(Zsh probably has even more extended wildcards that are able to match only files.)

If you have more subdirectories and don't want to touch them, tools such as `find` or `fd` can be used to operate on specific items only, in this case only files:

```
find /participant/data -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv {} /participant/data/subdir/ \;
```

This would be slightly more efficient using `mv -t` and `-exec +`:

```
find /participant/data -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv -t /participant/data/subdir {} +
```

The previous (slower) example can also be written as a shell `for` loop:

```
for x in /participant/data/*; do
    if [[ -f $x ]]; then mv "$x" /participant/data/subdirectory/; fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `*` instead of `*.*` to include all files independant of the filename.

But this would also inculde directories, also including `subdirectory`, so you have to exclude it when moving the files.

This is possible with the extended pattern matching functions. First you have to enable them (for the current session):

`$ shopt -s extglob`

Then you can address all files except one using `path/!(excludedFile)`

Implemented in `mv`:

`$ mv /participant/data/!(subdirectory) /participant/data/subdirectory/`

There are more options to move all files except one: https://www.baeldung.com/linux/move-all-files-except-one

Comment: I like how you've generalized the problem: it's essentially about moving all files except one. The fact that that one file is at the same time the target directory is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing for the situation you describe is to:

```
cd /participant/data
mkdir .tempname
mv * .tmpname
mv .tmpname subdirectory
```

The * will match all directory entries that are not hidden, that is, all that do not start with a dot. Since we've temporarily started the subdirectory name with a dot, it doesn't match and all the entries in data will be moved.
Now, if you have some entries that you do not want to move, such as other subdirectories, you'll have to use one of more complex methods, such as those in user1686's detailed answer.